# Are ARC-170 fighters still able to fly hypersonic with deflector shields on in canon?

Tags: star-wars

In Legends, it was said that when an ARC-170 fighter had its shields on, it could fly 44x times faster in an atmosphere, hitting hypersonic speed. Has any canon sourcebook said that as well?

Comment: What? Where is the Legends source on this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is still canon according to the 2020 edition of *Complete Vehicles*:

> The ARC-170's deflector shields disperse the heat generated by air resistance in atmospheric flight, enabling the craft to reach hypersonic speeds.
>
> <sub>[*Star Wars: Complete Vehicles* (2020)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Complete_Vehicles,_New_Edition), page 82: "ARC-170 Fighter"</sub>

I'm not sure where the "44 times faster" figure came from, but the [2006 edition of *Complete Cross-Sections*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Complete_Cross-Sections) does list the ARC-170's max airspeed as 44,000 kph—maybe that's what you're thinking of? The Canon cross-sections don't include speed figures, however, so it's unclear how much faster in Canon it can travel than the 1,235 kph real-world speed of sound.